# PHP extracting data from text

Tags: php, mysql, text-mining

I have an old windows 95 program that exports data without account numbers, seasonal accounts, and if accounts contains a sub account.

I am, however, able to print customer information and notes that has the above information to a pdf file and copy that text to notepad; which I would like to extract the data.

The order the data: 1) page headers (I do not need this data.)

**Company Name**

**Customer Information and Notes**

**Computed Monday, August 10 2015 Page 1**

2) standard titles and 3) the data after titles:

**Ser Name:** Block, Sunny **Route:** 1

**Address:** 3354 ASPEN RD. **Frequency:** Monthly

**Address:** ST PETE, GA 33333 **Week/Day:** First Monday

**City State Zip:** data **Sched Time (HH:MM):** 10:00A

**Ser Phone:** 555-1212 **Service:** BASIC SERVICE

**Bill to:** BLOCK,SUNNY **Rate ($):** 24.00

**Company Name**

**Customer Information and Notes**

**Computed Monday, August 10 2015 Page 2**

**Address:** 1123 Sligh **Terms:** CASH

**Address:** Apt B

**notes:** Sunny has a mean dog

Do not enter unless dog is put up

Then it loops to next customers data and so on.

The main titles never change, such as, ser name, route, address, notes, phone. There is a set number of titles in order; however, the title **notes:** can take 1 -16 lines; and the header is random throughout the data. and although the titles are in order, address is titled 4 times for both service- line 1 and line 2 and billing addresses- line 1 and line 2.

I would like to set variables to these titles and only take what's after them; the extraction part through PHP. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: PDFs are a bitch to extract text from, are you absolutely sure there is no other way (postscript :/)

Comment: is there no delimiter between each customer? e.g. after notes: .. there's arbitrary stuff and then goes right into the next company name?

Comment: @AlecTeal printing to pdf or xps is the only way I can get the legacy account numbers and other data I am not able to extract through the built-in program commands.

Comment: @CrayonViolent No delimters, just titles and the data the flows after.

Comment: I wanted to note: the titles for the data are in order for each customer, even if no data is entered in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I don't think it's possible for a perfect solution, but FWIW, maybe this is good enough for you.**

Without a known / reliable delimiter between clients, I can't think of any good way you can get the notes without having the header stuff for the next company included, unless you can do something involving a big lookup table of all client names.

I do have (an ugly) regex that may reliably help as far as the other stuff though:

```
$content='[the contents of your file]';
preg_match_all('~(Ser Name|Route|Address|Frequency|Week/Day|City State Zip|Sched Time \(HH:MM\)|Ser Phone|Service|Bill to|Rate \(\$\)|Terms|notes):\s*((?:(?!Ser Name|Route|Address|Frequency|Week/Day|City State Zip|Sched Time \(HH:MM\)|Ser Phone|Service|Bill to|Rate \(\$\)|Terms|notes).)+)~is',$content,$matches);
```

So this basically looks for the "header" and puts into first captured group, and then matches up to the next "header" and puts that into 2nd captured group.

Perhaps this is good enough for you, but TBH I can't think of anything better you can do, unless you can improve your extraction to a better format.

So your example data would output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Ser Name: Block, Sunny 
            [1] => Route: 1


            [2] => Address: 3354 ASPEN RD. 
            [3] => Frequency: Monthly


            [4] => Address: ST PETE, GA 33333 
            [5] => Week/Day: First Monday


            [6] => City State Zip: data 
            [7] => Sched Time (HH:MM): 10:00A


            [8] => Ser Phone: 555-1212 
            [9] => Service: BASIC SERVICE


            [10] => Bill to: BLOCK,SUNNY 
            [11] => Rate ($): 24.00

Company Name

Customer Information and Notes

Computed Monday, August 10 2015 Page 2


            [12] => Address: 1123 Sligh 
            [13] => Terms: CASH


            [14] => Address: Apt B


            [15] => notes: Sunny has a mean dog
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Ser Name
            [1] => Route
            [2] => Address
            [3] => Frequency
            [4] => Address
            [5] => Week/Day
            [6] => City State Zip
            [7] => Sched Time (HH:MM)
            [8] => Ser Phone
            [9] => Service
            [10] => Bill to
            [11] => Rate ($)
            [12] => Address
            [13] => Terms
            [14] => Address
            [15] => notes
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Block, Sunny 
            [1] => 1


            [2] => 3354 ASPEN RD. 
            [3] => Monthly


            [4] => ST PETE, GA 33333 
            [5] => First Monday


            [6] => data 
            [7] => 10:00A


            [8] => 555-1212 
            [9] => BASIC SERVICE


            [10] => BLOCK,SUNNY 
            [11] => 24.00

Company Name

Customer Information and Notes

Computed Monday, August 10 2015 Page 2


            [12] => 1123 Sligh 
            [13] => CASH


            [14] => Apt B


            [15] => Sunny has a mean dog
        )

)
```

Comment: Getting the content is the crux of the question.

Comment: @AlecTeal well, not really.. he has `$content` in a file.. the crux of the question is reliably parsing it into buckets

Comment: I think this is a start. I can probably filter and delete lines that start with company name, customer info and notes, and computed date, and clean that up. Then the flow of data would be more in order of a (title: data title: data). I do understand the data not might stay intact. I have over 3000 records to loop through.